# How to get the Current Computer name or terminal name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I Need a Query of getting the Current Computer name or Terminal Name  using PostgreSQL Database
Please Give me the solution ASAP

Comment: -1 for "ASAP" - you are asking for free help here

Comment: What "computer name"? The hostname of the database server? Or the hostname of the client?

Comment: Hi,Here Computer name means Machine Name.
Here,What I Need is, How TO Get the Query OF  Current Machine Name Using PostgreSQL???

Answer (score 2):

Below may work for your needs. If you are on the console be careful with the results, likely you don't want to kill a postgres owned process.

```
SELECT inet_client_addr();


SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE client_addr = inet_client_addr();
```

*http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/423851-retrieve-ip-client-postgres
*http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-stop-a-query-td1924086.html

Comment: Hi,
   Thanks For your given Solution.
But Here I am not getting the computer's name or terminal Name.